# Direct connection from the CTAN package name to the files of the package

Tags: installing, online, ctan

Is there a way to download the package files only be knowing the CTAN package name (which can be a (La)TeX package, class, bundle, font, etc.)?
I'm aware that `http://www.ctan.org/pkg/<NAME>` shows the package entry and `tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/<NAME>.html` shows the similar catalogue entry. Both of them link to the CTAN directory holding the package files, which is fine for manual browsing. I however look for an *automatic way* to retrieve the package files (mainly the DTX and INS files) *without* needing to parse a HTML page for the directory URL. The idea is to write a script which allows to install most CTAN packages directly from CTAN.

To elaborate: I'm looking for an online resource where I can use the CTAN package name in an URL and I get redirected to the CTAN directory of this package, on any mirror. This is similar to http://texdoc.net just not for the documentation but for the DTX/INS files. If there is no such thing I probably will create it myself (by altering the some source code of [CTAN-HG](http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/)), but I see no reason to duplicate something which already exists.

Comment: Have you looked at the TL scripts for updating packages? They already have the (long) list of 'special cases' you'd need to allow for.

Comment: @JosephWright: I didn't saw these scripts yet. Can you give me a link, please? However, I have experience with exceptions from my work on CTAN-HG.

Comment: Now there you have me. I know these scripts exist, but I'd have to ask on the TL list where they actually are :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: Did you mean exceptions to get the CTAN path from the name or for the actual installation?

Comment: ctan hosts allow any directory to be retrieved as a zip file so if you know the directory you can get all the files, in one go,

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Did you see the new announcement: https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/a78f67825bce4462?hl=de#

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Yes, I did. This sounds very interesting. This question might even have something to do with it because I got contacted by a member of the CTAN team about it.

Comment: For the scripts in TL see http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/libexec/ctan2tds?view=markup, http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/bin/tlpkg-ctan-check?view=markup, ... but these are not standalone and might need minor adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

[Combining comments into a answer]

You can retrieve any directory from CTAN as a `.zip` file so if you know the directory you can get all the files, in one go. TeX Live uses a series of scripts, which can be downloaded from  http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/libexec/ctan2tds?view=markup and http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/bin/tlpkg-ctan-check?view=markup, but these are not standalone and might need minor adjustments.